# CSS3 li Menu with border-radius and li:hover

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of an issue with a CSS3 menu with rounded corners, and I'm not sure if it's the way I'm applying my classes that are causing my issue.  Please note that in my examples below I have omitted the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` variants of the code in order to save space, but they are present in my code.

I have a `<div>` tag containing a customised `<ul>` menu, to allow drop down functionality and am also utilising `li:hover` to highlight the menu selected.  And, for the first time ever (in my experience), IE actually worked flawlessly first time whereas Firefox and Chrome required some tweaking.

I was having an issue with the `li:hover` state of my far left menu item, as when it was hovered it squared off the corners and then after the 'mouseout' it also affected the `border-radius` of the containing `<ul>` tag.  I was able to fix the issue by applying the `border-radius` to a div tag first and then hiding the overflow, however as the menu items contained drop-down lists they were not being displayed.  I therefore set the left menu item with a class of `menu_end` and set the `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` of the `li` and `li:hover` to match the `border-radius` of the `<ul>` tag, which I thought had fixed the problem.

```
.menu_end {
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.menu_end li:hover {
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

However, I've noticed that the sub-menu that is created in the `li:hover` state has also inherited these style with rounded left corners, and I can't seem to clear them.  I've tried adding:

```
.menu_end ul li ul li{
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.menu_end ul li ul li:hover {
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

Which for some reason doesn't work.  I've also tried assigning the nested `<li>` elements their own class:

```
.menu_end_drop li {
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
.menu_end_drop li:hover {
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

Neither method seems to work, and strangely if I apply a style to just `border-radius` without specifying a location, it effects the two previously unspecified corners but not the top left and bottom left corners.

I thought this might be to do with the order of my styles, but my understanding is that and styles applied later in a css file supersedes any previous styles, so I'm at a bit of a loss!

I've included everything in this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Z5qWe/2/

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Best Wishes,

Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because of this:

```
.menu_end li:hover {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

This should **only apply to direct descendants** (so we use `>`).

Replace it with this:

```
.menu_end > li:hover {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5qWe/5/

Comment: @JoeP No problems :). Glad I could help.